# DATETIME and TIMESTAMP Length/Values Error

Tags: mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin

I was using `int` type for storing datetime type data. For the convenience of getting the data in specific range from MySQL, I tried changing it to `TIMESTAMP/DATETIME` but it is giving the error as in [the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIpWC.png) in both the cases. The format for datatype `TIMESTAMP/DATETIME` is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` which is 19 character long.

I could not get a proper tutorial/article to get knowledge about this error/issue.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIpWC.png)

Comment: Don't get hang up on tutorials all the time. It makes much more sense to read up on stuff like this directly in the official documentation. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html

Comment: So the limitation 6 means that it is fractional value? I guess I will get the results if feed the database with `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. Thanks for pointing out this cruicial point regarding this datatype although I have gone through articles in http://dev.mysql.com/.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When defining a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP field, there's no need to specify the length.

This is what the error message refers to:

> A DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision
>
> MySQL permits fractional seconds for TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. To define a column that includes a fractional seconds part, use the syntax type_name(fsp), where type_name is TIME, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP, and fsp is the fractional seconds precision. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (t TIME(3), dt DATETIME(6));
```

Abstract from [CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

```
| TIME[(fsp)]
| TIMESTAMP[(fsp)]
| DATETIME[(fsp)]
```

Documentation:

- [The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)
- [Date and Time Type Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html)